# Negative value prints as big number in python

Tags: python, unsigned, pymodbustcp

im pulling data from a modbusTCP server, but when i should receive a negative value it shows as a big number.

```
self.export = self.c.read_holding_registers(37113, 2)[1]
```

I know it has something to do with it being signed or unsigned but im really having trouble solving it.

```
    print("export:      " + "{:02f}W".format(self.inverter.export))
    print("exportBytes: " + "{:16b}W".format(self.inverter.export))
    print("export:      " + "{:02f}W".format(self.inverter.export))
    print("export 1:    " + "{:16b}W".format(1))
    print("export-1:    " + "{:16b}W".format(-1))
```

Prints out

```
export:      59142.000000kW
exportBytes: 1110011100000110kW
export:      59142.000000kW
export 1:                   1kW
export-1:                  -1kW
```

Any guesses?

Comment: what does `type(self.inverter.export)` returns?

Comment: it returns <class 'int'>

Comment: how do you get data from `modbusTCP` ? If you get it as bytes then maybe you should use `struct` to convert it to integer. OR maybe you should write own function to convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

The bytes received is implicitley cast to an unsigned int.

To convert to a signed int we

1. use the Int.to_bytes() to get the bytes and
2. use the int.from_bytes() to get the signet int.

```
varBytes = theInteger.to_bytes(2, 'big')                               # getting raw bytes
signedInt = int.from_bytes(varBytes , byteorder='big', signed = True)  # getting signet int vale
```

copied to an int as being unsigned.The "int" that is received is implicitley cast to an int by python.

Answer (score 0):

Mads' solution I think will work, but this is maybe more illustrative of what's going on:

```python
def int16_decode(uint16_val):
    if uint16_val > 0x8000:
        uint16_val -= 0x10000
    return uint16_val
```

It's how signed ints are stored in memory.  int16 is like uint16 except the most-significant-bit is reserved as the sign bit.  So if you read a negative int16 as a uint16, it will be very big since most significant bit of 16 is 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).